# Is the RHEL 7 version of FreeRadius not affected by RHSA-2017:1759 (or similar)?

Tags: vulnerability, cve, updates, patching

[In July 2017, multiple security issues have been found in FreeRadius 2.x.x and 3.0.x.](http://freeradius.org/security/fuzzer-2017.html)  RHEL 6 uses FreeRadius 2.x.x and Red Hat has released security advisory [RHSA-2017:1759](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2017:1759).  However, for RHEL 7, no security advisory exists, as far as I can see.

However, the latest version on RHEL at the time of writing this is **freeradius-3.0.4-8.el7_3**, and the issues are fixed in FreeRadius 3.0.15.  I know that Red Hat can backport certain fixes from newer versions in its packages, but is this what happened?

How can I find out if I'm secure against these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dig into the [CVE detail](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2017-10978) listed for the first CVE on that RHSA, it appears that RHEL 7 is **affected** but not yet addressed.  Since it is listed as "affected" and not "will not fix", Red Hat will likely release a new RHSA or update the existing one as soon as they have the fix backported for RHEL 7.

[image: Red Hat Errata for CVE-2017-10978]

Note that there is an RHSA titled "[Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (freeradius)](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2017:1581)", but it is older (RHSA 1581 vs. 1759 for the new RHEL 6 RHSA) and addresses a different CVE.  It is, in fact, the one that produced the freeradius-3.0.4-8.el7_3 that you're looking at.

Comment: I had noticed the other CVE too, but it's not related to this CVE, as you said. I'll punch the actual CVE into the Red Hat site next time, today I learned. I had expected Red Hat to release an RHSA immediately, even if no patch is available, but that's apparently not how it works.